Excel.FormattedNumberCellValue is not working with custom formula response
{
   type: Excel.CellValueType.formattedNumber,
   basicValue: Number(value),
   numberFormat: '#,##0.00',
}; 

this is how I am formatting my response in custom formula response returning in excel like [[formattedResponse]] this but it shows ##### in the cell how to set this formatted response in excel javascript api.

Normally if you see ##### in a cell in Excel it means the width of the cell is not enough to show the value. Did you check that?

how can we adjust from the custom formula

I don't know in angular and that's why I posted a comment, but manually the process would be following Change the column width to automatically fit the contents (AutoFit)

This doesn't get resolved via Angular so to speak, its the office-js API. See --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangeformat?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-rangeformat-autofitcolumns-member(1)
